# Android documentation meaning of "added in API level X"

Tags: android

Can someone clarify this for me?

- Does the "added in API level 22" means that the minSdk for using is >= 22?
- How is it possible the **BaseInterpolator** been added at API 22 and the **DecelerateInterpolator** at API 1? I mean the **DecelerateInterpolator** has it as the parent class.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1):

From the very beginning, `DecelerateInterpolator` really did not inherit from `BaseInterpolator`, from Android 5.0 (api level 21) or below run this version:

```java
@HasNativeInterpolator
public class DecelerateInterpolator implements Interpolator, NativeInterpolatorFactory {
    // implementation
}
```

[Full source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/c8ac775659fd252ce2cc9a61837c170ff70f0a1a/core/java/android/view/animation/DecelerateInterpolator.java)

---

But at api level 22, they added new `BaseInterpolator` class, and now `DecelerateInterpolator` became:

```java
@HasNativeInterpolator
public class DecelerateInterpolator extends BaseInterpolator implements NativeInterpolatorFactory {
    // implementation
}
```

[Full source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/d422dc358f0100106dc07d7b903201eb9b043b11/core/java/android/view/animation/DecelerateInterpolator.java)

Android 5.1 (api level 22) or above run this code, and you can use `BaseInterpolator`

Comment: So you infer that the "added in API 22" doesn't necessarily mean that I can only use it when API >= 22?

Comment: No, you can only use it if API >= 22.

Comment: Yes but in this example I can use DecelerateInterpolator with API < 22

Comment: On API < 22, `DecelerateInterpolator`'s parents are `Interpolator` and `NativeInterpolatorFactory`, not `BaseInterpolator` so you can use it without error.